# USB mouse on Ubuntu stops working

Tags: 14.04, usb, bash, mouse

Many times my mouse USB suddenly stops working, though the trackpad works just fine. I have to click it to make it work again. I have found the following solution:

```
sudo bash
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/control; do echo on > $i; done
```

However, I have to execute this script every time the problem occurs. What is the true reason behind it? How can I fix it permanently?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: ***Let us assume this is on a Notebook (or tablet).*** This may be specific to which USB port is used, with (at least) one providing continuous power (for device charging, or mouse/dongle use). *This may also be a setting in BIOS setup.*

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the power management switches off usb devices in order to save power after a certain period of inactivity. Although there are solutions to solve this manually I recommend to install software called tlp.

`sudo apt-get install tlp`

This software offers options to control power management in a  safe way without having to set things manually in relevant files, like what you've found to be a solution. It works equally good at both laptops and desktops.

More info about tlp can be found at several sites like for example this one: `http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-tlp-0-6-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-12-04-and-derivative-systems/`

Comment: I see `unable to located package tlp` when I try to install. Is it possible it has another name? I'm on 14.04.

Comment: Please take a look at the address I mentioned above. The package has its own repository that you have to add manually.

Comment: Try to reload mouse driver with : 1- sudo rmmod usbhid |
2- sudo modprobe usbhid